# Remote control audio player (e.g. Groove-Music)

Tags: audio, windows-10-mobile, groove

I'd like to write an app for My Band2 that should be able to simply change the audio track when I hit a button on my Band2. I'll use this because my car can't Play Audio via Bluetooth. So I bought a Bluetooth dongle but I'm unable to change tracks or simply to pause it. So a 3 button app on my Band2 should do a good job.

I've found a lot of examples to do so with Background Audio Players in a self written app.

But I'd like to remote Control the standard player, which is Groove-Music for me.

Any suggestions to do so? Can you please give me a start on that?

Thanks,
Jo